# how to give estimate to client about payment?

Tags: software-development, estimation

I am new in software field. I have done M.C.A. and haven't done any deal with client. Now i have one client who has a requirement of C++ software. I can cope up with requirement but I don't know how to deal with him.

I want to know:

- how to give him estimation of payment?
- how to give him time to deliver a software?

Comment: Estimating is complex.  I do not think you will get the level of guidance you need here.  You need to find someone who knows how to do this to guide you and you need to pick up some basic PM 101 books.

Comment: Maybe a too complex question for a single topic. Have a look on the topics within the 'estimating' tag for instance, and you may have part of your question answered. http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/estimating

Comment: Maybe this question does not fit PMSE requirements... since both questions may have books of material discussing about. From FAQ: "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much." http://pm.stackexchange.com/faq#questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it all C++? I mean is the entire application in C/C++ only? Either ways here are some techniques you can apply at an 'early stage'

1. Do a function point analysis to gauge the size of the software and then use parametric models like COCOMO II to get the amount of time it'd take to complete this in man-months. Divide that by the number of the people on the project and multiply that by their salary - should give you a number. The tool also gives you pessimistic and optimistic estimates - so you basically get a range. At an early stage that's pretty much all you can do.
2. If FP-analysis seems alien do SLOC based estimates - tools like COCOMO take both metrics. Repeat everything else from step 1. (good if the application is written in a single language)
3. You could also do 'story point estimation' from the agile world - take a high level breakdown of the desired feature-sets, guess their size (magnitude), guess your speed of development (velocity): Time = magnitude * velocity. Use the same man-month+salary based calculation as above to get the overall cost
4. Create a work break down structure and provide an estimate (you can find some details here: http://answers.onstartups.com/q/33791/8167)
5. Read books and figure out what works best and what you want to try like what Thomas has suggested.

In short - read/research/apply - if you fail, you'll learn, if you succeed, you'll still learn so be brave!! :)

Answer (score 2):

The leading books about software project management and software estimation are Steve McConnell's [Rapid Development: Taming Wild Software Schedules](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1556159005), [Software Project Survival Guide](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1572316217), and [Software Estimation: Demystifying the Black Art](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735605351).

Aside from reading these books, and other software project management or software estimation resources, I agree with David Espina and Tiago Cardoso's comments - this is a very complex topic and a lot has been written about it, both in a number of books, papers, and other questions here in the [estimating](/questions/tagged/estimating) tag.